# AWS Route53 private hosted zone to Internal Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

**Setup**

I've got the below configured in a single AWS account.  If it helps, the Client is Kibana and the Service is ElasticSearch.

[image]

**What I'm trying to do**

Route traffic from the "Client" EC2 instances to an Internal Application Load Balancer using a Route53 Alias Record in a Private Hosted Zone.

I've followed AWS's documentation, and as I understand it, I should just be able to create the alias record in the Private Hosted zone... and the good new is, I can

[image]

- The Hosted Zone name is `internal.my_company.com`
- The Alias name is `service.internal.my_company.com`

**Problem**

If I open a Session Manager terminal on one of the Clients and run the following:

```
curl <internal_load_balancer_dns>:9200
```

I get a response from the Service as expected

However, if I run

```
curl service.internal.my_company.com:9200
```

I get the following response

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: service.internal.my_company.com
```

I've googled around, but can't find anything recent relating to this.  Have I missed something in letting Route53 know how to reach the Internal Load Balancer?

Let me know if you need more information about the setup.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the VPC hosting your private subnets associated with the private hosted zone?  (Probably so, since you have to pick a VPC when creating the zone.)

For the VPC, did you enable DnsHostnames and DnsSupport?

VPC --> Actions

Comment: Yes, DnsHostnames and DnsSupport are both enabled :(